# usort with extra parameters to determine the exact type or sort needed

Tags: php, function, sorting, usort

I have this awful sorting function, which started giving me problems when two were called on the same page.  It is highly likely that it would be called many times on the same page.

I wish to be able to call the sorting function and send specific parameters to determine the type of sort.  These include the field that is being sorted by (`$arr['key']`), whether it's a string or integer (`strcmp` vs `x - y`) and also the direction to compare (`asc` vs `desc`).

How can I do this in a non-crazy, complicating and messy way?  I tried lots and lots of searching, but I found lots of things using objects and classes and it confused me and I didn't see how to send more parameters.

Any help, even if this is a duplicate question and you have the answer, would be greatly greatly appreciated!

```
//awful sorting function
switch($sort) {
case 'photoname_asc':
    function a_compare($a, $b) {
        $t1 = $a['photoname'];
        $t2 = $b['photoname'];
        return strcmp($t1, $t2);
    }
    usort($photos, 'a_compare');
    default;
    break;
case 'photoname_desc':
    function a_compare($a, $b) {
        $t1 = $a['photoname'];
        $t2 = $b['photoname'];
        return strcmp($t2, $t1);
    }
    usort($photos, 'a_compare');
    break;
case 'dateup_asc':
    function a_compare($a, $b) {
        $t1 = $a['id'];
        $t2 = $b['id'];
        return $t1 - $t2;
    }
    usort($photos, 'a_compare');
    break;
case 'dateup_desc':
    function a_compare($a, $b) {
        $t1 = $a['id'];
        $t2 = $b['id'];
        return $t2 - $t1;
    }
    usort($photos, 'a_compare');
    break;
 }
```

Thanks so very much.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't "send more parameters"? Just put your sorting code in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a function that condenses your switch statement. Warning untested but should do the trick.

```
function photoStort(array &$photos, $key, $order) {
    if ($order !== 'desc' && $order !== 'asc') {
        return false;
    }

    usort($photos, function($a, $b) use ($key, $order) {
        $t1 = $a[$key];
        $t2 = $b[$key];

        if (is_string($t1) && is_string($t2)) {
            if ($order === 'asc') {
                return strcmp($t1, $t2);
            } else {
                return strcmp($t2, $t1);
            }
        } elseif (is_int($t1) && is_int($t2)) {
            if ($order === 'asc') {
                return $t1 - $t2;
            } else {
                return $t2 - $t1;
            }
        } else {
            trigger_error('Invalid type in photoSort!', E_WARNING);
        }
    });
}
$photos = array(/* Photos */);

//ex 1
photoSort($photos, 'photoname', 'asc');

//ex 2
photoSort($photos, 'id', 'desc');
```

PHP 5.2 solution

```
function usortCallback($a, $b, $key, $order) {
    $t1 = $a[$key];
    $t2 = $b[$key];

    if (is_string($t1) && is_string($t2)) {
        if ($order === 'asc') {
            return strcmp($t1, $t2);
        } else {
            return strcmp($t2, $t1);
        }
    } elseif (is_int($t1) && is_int($t2)) {
        if ($order === 'asc') {
            return $t1 - $t2;
        } else {
            return $t2 - $t1;
        }
    } else {
        trigger_error('Invalid type in photoSort!', E_WARNING);
    }
}

function photoSort(array &$photos, $key, $order) {
    if ($order !== 'desc' && $order !== 'asc') {
        return false;
    }

    usort($photos, create_function('$a, $b', 'return usortCallback($a, $b, "' . $key . '", "' . $order . '");'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick and what looks like an excellent suggestion!  However, I am running on PHP 5.2 and I forgot to mention it earlier.  I'm pretty sure that 
    `usort($photos, function($a, $b) use ($key, $order)`
doesn't work on it.  Is there a simple replacement? I am creating a plugin, and don't want it to be limited to 5.3.  Thanks!

Comment: I added an alternative for 5.2.

Comment: For some reason I didn't get this comment, and actually figured it out on myself.  I did it slightly differently but based it completely on the way you had done it, but your method is better and I shall adapt.  Thanks!

Comment: @maxiscool hey, maybe you can assist me further.  Using your function, I'm getting this error in my error log.  
`[07-Jun-2013 19:19:12] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant photoname - assumed 'photoname' in location : runtime-created function on line 1` for both photoname and asc, or whatever else the sort is set to.  The notice is triggered on the usort create function line.  Thanks!

Comment: It needs quotes around the arguments.
    'return usortCallback($a, $b, "' . $key . '", "' . $order . '");'